# Route [cource] not definedin Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have the following link in my Blade file to link `cource.blade.php` in the view folder.

```php
<a href="{{ route('cource') }}" class="list-group-item">
    <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> <span>Cource</span>
</a>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/cource', function () {
    return view('cource');
});
```

I get the following error message, how can I fix this problem?

> Route [cource] not defined. (View:
>   D:\exam\curd\resources\views\sidebar\sidebar.blade.php) (View:
>   D:\exam\curd\resources\views\sidebar\sidebar.blade.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must provide the route alias/name:

```
Route::get('/cource', ['as' => 'cource', function () {
    return view('cource');
}]);
```

or

```
Route::get('/cource', function () {
    return view('cource');
})->name('cource');
```

Comment: ok, it is working fine but I have one problem here. then how can work welcome page without name route `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});`

Comment: @Root `<a href="{{url('/')}}" ...>` for that one. Or give it a name.

Answer (score 1):

Function `route` takes the name of the route, so the route should be:

```
Route::get('/cource', function () {
    return view('cource');
})->name('cource');
```

[Documetation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing) (see: **Generating URLs To Named Routes**)

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to name all your routes, so your route should be:

```
Route::get('/cource', function () {
    return view('cource');
})->name('cource');
```

and for the welcome route should do something similar, you provide the name that you want for all your routes.

```
Route::get('/', function () { 
return view('welcome'); 
})->name('home');
```